# Run multiple python scripts to a specific path

Tags: python

I am trying to run multiple files from different paths. I was wondering if I can have the results in the same folders as the scripts are located.

```
import os
print ("Starting tablete_tot")
os.system(r"python D:\python\test\tableta_wi_fi_tot.py")
print ("tablete_tot ended")
print ("Starting tasatura_fara_fir_noutati")
os.system(r"python D:\python\test\tasatura_fara_fir_noutati.py")
print ("tasatura_fara_fir_noutati ended")
print ("Starting mouse_pad_tot")
os.system(r"python D:\python\test\x\mouse_pad_tot.py")
print ("mouse_pad_tot ended")
```

I need the result to be in the same file as the scripts.

Comment: You might be better off using a shell script rather than python for this, `os.system` invokes a shell anyway, so you can shell `>` redirection.  Since you are using Windows, that would use `cmd.exe` by default, and `>` works fine.

Comment: Please have a look at [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) when you have a while, it gives you much more flexibility while running other scripts.

Comment: "I need the result to be in the same file as the scripts." => __which__ "results" ??? Are we supposed to guess what your scripts do ???